# How to merge more than one push notification in android?

Tags: android

I have problem with merge more than one notification into one message like whats app gives the notification. I tried with increment "++Notification_Id" that gives me separate notification.

I tried my best but something i can't understand how to do like this.

Comment: Please write some code. None can help you in this way..

Comment: here is my method.. http://notepad.cc/share/czgY4Bm3rp

Answer (score 0):

This should help : http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html

Basically you save your current notification id and then update it as you wish.

But some sample code from your app would help.

Comment: here is my method.. notepad.cc/share/czgY4Bm3rp